# Returning zero when it shouldn't

Tags: java, android, eclipse, return, coordinates

The method below keeps returning 0, and I cannot figure out why!  Please help!

```
    currentLocation.setLatitude(38.03211);
    currentLocation.setLongitude(-78.51002);
```

and longitude/latitude of if loc is
                38.03161,
                -78.51075,

```
public double getDistance(HistoricalLocation loc) {

    return (double) Math.abs(Math.sqrt((currentLocation.getLatitude() - loc
            .getLatitude())
            * (currentLocation.getLatitude() - loc.getLatitude())
            + (currentLocation.getLongitude() - loc.getLongitude())
            * (currentLocation.getLongitude() - loc.getLongitude())));

}
```

Comment: Post details of your logcat.

Comment: are you testing it on device?

Comment: what is value of `loc`? you only show the value of `currentLocation`

Comment: loc is an object with the long and lat posted above. and yes i am testing it on a device and ran a check...it comes back exactly 0

Comment: got it! i was doing the sqrt first, and it came up as NaN (im assuming) thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the squareroot of the absolute value, not the other way around. It is probably coming up NaN which is just setting it to zero or something like that.

(this fixed it)

Comment: nice to see someone sharing after fixing the problem +1